# Neo4j / REST concurrency issue

Tags: neo4j, cypher

So I tried to use the new ***merge*** syntax to reduce the amount of operations I need to ensure that two nodes exist and link them. Here's the basic idea:

```
merge (first:Label{key:'value'})
merge (second:Label{key:'value'})
create unique first-[:rel]->second
set first.prop="x"
set second.prop="y"
```

That would've taken at least 3 calls to the API with the 1.9 systax, to make sure that each of the nodes exists first and link them (and set properties) in a third request.

It appears that my batches (full of these requests) do their job properly, but also throw some exceptions (sometimes, unpredictable). Here's what my log says:

```
de.ibm.ica.tripletstore.TripletWriterCypher2.process(TripletWriterCypher2.java:161) - FATAL [15:48:58,954] [ {
  "method" : "POST",
  "to" : "/cypher",
  "body" : {
    "query" : "CYPHER 2.0 merge (x:`person`{`key`:'John Doe'}) merge (y:`occupation`{`key`:'Developer'})  create unique x-[r:`works as`]-y with x, y, r SET x.`annotation`='com.ibm.ica.tutorial.anno.en.Person' SET y.`annotation`='com.ibm.ica.tutorial.anno.en.Occupation'  return x.key, y.key, type(r)"
  },
  "id" : 0
}, {
  "method" : "POST",
  "to" : "/cypher",
  "body" : {
    "query" : "CYPHER 2.0 merge (x:`person`{`key`:'John Doe'}) merge (y:`organization`{`key`:'IBM'})  create unique x-[r:`works for`]-y with x, y, r SET x.`annotation`='com.ibm.ica.tutorial.anno.en.Person' SET y.`country`='United States ' SET y.`industry`='Software & Services ' SET y.`annotation`='com.ibm.ica.tutorial.anno.en.Company'  return x.key, y.key, type(r)"
  },
  "id" : 1
}, {
  "method" : "POST",
  "to" : "/cypher",
  "body" : {
    "query" : "CYPHER 2.0 merge (x:`person`{`key`:'Ginny Rometty'}) merge (y:`organization`{`key`:'IBM'})  create unique x-[r:`works for`]-y with x, y, r SET x.`annotation`='com.ibm.ica.tutorial.anno.en.Person' SET y.`country`='United States ' SET y.`industry`='Software & Services ' SET y.`annotation`='com.ibm.ica.tutorial.anno.en.Company'  return x.key, y.key, type(r)"
  },
  "id" : 2
}, {
  "method" : "POST",
  "to" : "/cypher",
  "body" : {
    "query" : "CYPHER 2.0 merge (x:`person`{`key`:'Ginny Rometty'}) merge (y:`occupation`{`key`:'CEO'})  create unique x-[r:`works as`]-y with x, y, r SET x.`annotation`='com.ibm.ica.tutorial.anno.en.Person' SET y.`annotation`='com.ibm.ica.tutorial.anno.en.Occupation'  return x.key, y.key, type(r)"
  },
  "id" : 3
}, {
  "method" : "POST",
  "to" : "/cypher",
  "body" : {
    "query" : "CYPHER 2.0 merge (x:`person`{`key`:'Simon Sample'}) merge (y:`occupation`{`key`:'CTP'})  create unique x-[r:`works as`]-y with x, y, r SET x.`annotation`='com.ibm.ica.tutorial.anno.en.Person' SET y.`annotation`='com.ibm.ica.tutorial.anno.en.Occupation'  return x.key, y.key, type(r)"
  },
  "id" : 4
}, {
  "method" : "POST",
  "to" : "/cypher",
  "body" : {
    "query" : "CYPHER 2.0 merge (x:`person`{`key`:'Simon Sample'}) merge (y:`organization`{`key`:'IBM'})  create unique x-[r:`works for`]-y with x, y, r SET x.`annotation`='com.ibm.ica.tutorial.anno.en.Person' SET y.`country`='United States ' SET y.`industry`='Software & Services ' SET y.`annotation`='com.ibm.ica.tutorial.anno.en.Company'  return x.key, y.key, type(r)"
  },
  "id" : 5
}, {
  "method" : "POST",
  "to" : "/cypher",
  "body" : {
    "query" : "CYPHER 2.0 merge (x:`person`{`key`:'John Doe'}) merge (y:`person`{`key`:'Sally Sample'})  create unique x-[r:`coworker of`]-y with x, y, r SET x.`annotation`='com.ibm.ica.tutorial.anno.en.Person' SET y.`annotation`='com.ibm.ica.tutorial.anno.en.Person'  return x.key, y.key, type(r)"
  },
  "id" : 6
}, {
  "method" : "POST",
  "to" : "/cypher",
  "body" : {
    "query" : "CYPHER 2.0 merge (x:`person`{`key`:'Sam Sampleman'}) merge (y:`person`{`key`:'John Doe'})  create unique x-[r:`coworker of`]-y with x, y, r SET x.`annotation`='com.ibm.ica.tutorial.anno.en.Person' SET y.`annotation`='com.ibm.ica.tutorial.anno.en.Person'  return x.key, y.key, type(r)"
  },
  "id" : 7
}, {
  "method" : "POST",
  "to" : "/cypher",
  "body" : {
    "query" : "CYPHER 2.0 merge (x:`person`{`key`:'Johnny English'}) merge (y:`person`{`key`:'Sam Sampleman'})  create unique x-[r:`coworker of`]-y with x, y, r SET x.`annotation`='com.ibm.ica.tutorial.anno.en.Person' SET y.`annotation`='com.ibm.ica.tutorial.anno.en.Person'  return x.key, y.key, type(r)"
  },
  "id" : 8
}, {
  "method" : "POST",
  "to" : "/cypher",
  "body" : {
    "query" : "CYPHER 2.0 merge (x:`person`{`key`:'Johnny English'}) merge (y:`occupation`{`key`:'CTP'})  create unique x-[r:`works as`]-y with x, y, r SET x.`annotation`='com.ibm.ica.tutorial.anno.en.Person' SET y.`annotation`='com.ibm.ica.tutorial.anno.en.Occupation'  return x.key, y.key, type(r)"
  },
  "id" : 9
}, {
  "method" : "POST",
  "to" : "/cypher",
  "body" : {
    "query" : "CYPHER 2.0 merge (x:`person`{`key`:'Larry Page'}) merge (y:`organization`{`key`:'Google'})  create unique x-[r:`works for`]-y with x, y, r SET x.`annotation`='com.ibm.ica.tutorial.anno.en.Person' SET y.`country`='United States ' SET y.`industry`='Software & Services ' SET y.`annotation`='com.ibm.ica.tutorial.anno.en.Company'  return x.key, y.key, type(r)"
  },
  "id" : 10
}, {
  "method" : "POST",
  "to" : "/cypher",
  "body" : {
    "query" : "CYPHER 2.0 merge (x:`person`{`key`:'Larry Page'}) merge (y:`occupation`{`key`:'CEO'})  create unique x-[r:`works as`]-y with x, y, r SET x.`annotation`='com.ibm.ica.tutorial.anno.en.Person' SET y.`annotation`='com.ibm.ica.tutorial.anno.en.Occupation'  return x.key, y.key, type(r)"
  },
  "id" : 11
}, {
  "method" : "POST",
  "to" : "/cypher",
  "body" : {
    "query" : "CYPHER 2.0 merge (x:`person`{`key`:'Mark Elliot Zuckerberg'}) merge (y:`organization`{`key`:'Facebook'})  create unique x-[r:`works for`]-y with x, y, r SET x.`annotation`='com.ibm.ica.tutorial.anno.en.Person' SET y.`country`=null SET y.`industry`=null SET y.`annotation`='com.ibm.ica.tutorial.anno.en.Company'  return x.key, y.key, type(r)"
  },
  "id" : 12
}, {
  "method" : "POST",
  "to" : "/cypher",
  "body" : {
    "query" : "CYPHER 2.0 merge (x:`person`{`key`:'Mark Elliot Zuckerberg'}) merge (y:`occupation`{`key`:'CEO'})  create unique x-[r:`works as`]-y with x, y, r SET x.`annotation`='com.ibm.ica.tutorial.anno.en.Person' SET y.`annotation`='com.ibm.ica.tutorial.anno.en.Occupation'  return x.key, y.key, type(r)"
  },
  "id" : 13
} ]
de.ibm.ica.tripletstore.TripletWriterCypher2.process(TripletWriterCypher2.java:168) - ERROR [15:48:58,961] java.lang.Exception: Bad response code. 
{
  "message" : "{\r\n  \"message\" : \"If you create multiple elements, you can only create one of each.\",\r\n  \"exception\" : \"ParameterWrongTypeException\",\r\n  \"fullname\" : \"org.neo4j.cypher.ParameterWrongTypeException\",\r\n  \"stacktrace\" : [ \"org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.ExecuteUpdateCommandsPipe$$anonfun$org$neo4j$cypher$internal$pipes$ExecuteUpdateCommandsPipe$$exec$1.apply(ExecuteUpdateCommandsPipe.scala:59)\", \"org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.ExecuteUpdateCommandsPipe$$anonfun$org$neo4j$cypher$internal$pipes$ExecuteUpdateCommandsPipe$$exec$1.apply(ExecuteUpdateCommandsPipe.scala:59)\", \"org.neo4j.cypher.internal.helpers.CollectionSupport$$anon$1.next(CollectionSupport.scala:47)\", \"scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.next(Iterator.scala:372)\", \"scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)\", \"scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)\", \"scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)\", \"scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)\", \"scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)\", \"scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)\", \"org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ClosingIterator$$anonfun$next$1.apply(ClosingIterator.scala:45)\", \"org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ClosingIterator.failIfThrows(ClosingIterator.scala:84)\", \"org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ClosingIterator.next(ClosingIterator.scala:43)\", \"scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)\", \"org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ClosingIterator.foreach(ClosingIterator.scala:31)\", \"scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)\", \"scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ListBuffer.scala:178)\", \"scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ListBuffer.scala:45)\", \"scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:259)\", \"org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ClosingIterator.to(ClosingIterator.scala:31)\", \"scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toList(TraversableOnce.scala:243)\", \"org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ClosingIterator.toList(ClosingIterator.scala:31)\", \"org.neo4j.cypher.EagerPipeExecutionResult.<init>(EagerPipeExecutionResult.scala:32)\", \"org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.ExecutionPlanBuilder$$anonfun$5.apply(ExecutionPlanBuilder.scala:133)\", \"org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.ExecutionPlanBuilder$$anonfun$5.apply(ExecutionPlanBuilder.scala:131)\", \"org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.ExecutionPlanBuilder$$anon$1.execute(ExecutionPlanBuilder.scala:48)\", \"org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(ExecutionEngine.scala:70)\", \"org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(ExecutionEngine.scala:69)\", \"org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.prepare(ExecutionEngine.scala:131)\", \"org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:69)\", \"org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:84)\", \"org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.java:79)\", \"org.neo4j.server.rest.web.CypherService.cypher(CypherService.java:94)\", \"java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)\", \"org.neo4j.server.web.Jetty6WebServer.invokeDirectly(Jetty6WebServer.java:294)\", \"org.neo4j.server.rest.batch.NonStreamingBatchOperations.invoke(NonStreamingBatchOperations.java:55)\", \"org.neo4j.server.rest.batch.BatchOperations.performRequest(BatchOperations.java:188)\", \"org.neo4j.server.rest.batch.BatchOperations.parseAndPerform(BatchOperations.java:159)\", \"org.neo4j.server.rest.batch.NonStreamingBatchOperations.performBatchJobs(NonStreamingBatchOperations.java:48)\", \"org.neo4j.server.rest.web.BatchOperationService.batchProcess(BatchOperationService.java:117)\", \"org.neo4j.server.rest.web.BatchOperationService.performBatchOperations(BatchOperationService.java:71)\", \"java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)\" ]\r\n}",
  "exception" : "BatchOperationFailedException",
  "fullname" : "org.neo4j.server.rest.domain.BatchOperationFailedException",
  "stacktrace" : [ "org.neo4j.server.rest.batch.NonStreamingBatchOperations.invoke(NonStreamingBatchOperations.java:63)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.batch.BatchOperations.performRequest(BatchOperations.java:188)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.batch.BatchOperations.parseAndPerform(BatchOperations.java:159)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.batch.NonStreamingBatchOperations.performBatchJobs(NonStreamingBatchOperations.java:48)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.BatchOperationService.batchProcess(BatchOperationService.java:117)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.BatchOperationService.performBatchOperations(BatchOperationService.java:71)", "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)" ]
}
```

My guess is that firing multiple ***merges*** in short succession cause this issue, each trying to create the same node or something. Should a batch be executed "in order", according to the id of each element?

Comment: Michael, we will take a look and this might be a bug. Please don't rely on this for any production code yet, as it is experimental for the time bing :)

Comment: My code won't go into production anyway. It's meant for usage in PoCs of some text mining stuff. Merge seems to be the only well performing option here...

Comment: Btw, any chance to blog about this project? Seems supercool to use Cypher 2.0 to build a TripleStore!

Comment: Yup. I'm working on a series of videos & blog entries on these topics, as I promised before :)

Comment: I'm having a similar problem posting multiple statements to the transactional cypher endpoint on a 2.0M5 server. It seems that if I 'merge' a node once in a transaction I'm ok, if two statements in the same transaction have a 'merge' clause on the same node I get a `STATEMENT_EXECUTION_ERROR` with the message `"If you create multiple elements, you can only create one of each."`. I fully understand this is experimental, is there somewhere I can look to stay up to date with how merge, especially over REST, is coming along? (Also very keen on merge with larger patterns, that'll be grejhöjta.)